# Assert an integer is in list on pandas series

Tags: pandas

I have a DataFrame with two pandas Series as follow:

```
     value accepted_values
0      1    [1, 2, 3, 4]
1      2    [5, 6, 7, 8]
```

I would like to **efficiently** check if the value is in accepted_values using pandas methods.

I already know I can do something like the following, but I'm interested in a faster approach if there is one (took around 27 seconds on 1 million rows DataFrame)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"value":[1, 2], "accepted_values": [[1,2,3,4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]})

def check_first_in_second(values: pd.Series):
    return values[0] in values[1]

are_in_accepted_values = df[["value", "accepted_values"]].apply(
    check_first_in_second, axis=1
)

if not are_in_accepted_values.all():
    raise AssertionError("Not all value in accepted_values")
```

Comment: Please test both solutions and let me know how working. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if create `DataFrame` with list column you can compare by [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) and test if match at least one value per row by [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df["accepted_values"].tolist(), index=df.index)
are_in_accepted_values = df1.eq(df["value"]).any(axis=1).all()
```

Another idea:

```
are_in_accepted_values = all(v in a for v, a in df[["value", "accepted_values"]].to_numpy())
```

Comment: First solution works if I take a slice copy of my original dataframe. But it takes a lot of memory and I eventually get a MemoryError with the original dataframe.


Second solution works like a charm and is really fast. Thanks as lot !

Answer (score 0):

I found a little optimisation to your second idea. Using a bit more numpy than pandas makes it faster (more than 3x, tested with time.perf_counter()).

```
values = df["value"].values
accepted_values = df["accepted_values"].values

are_in_accepted_values = all(s in e for s, e in np.column_stack([values, accepted_values]))
```